# In Rig Veda, what is the reference to the "faith hymns"?

Tags: vedas, reference-request

In this answer by a [hindu scholar](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-basic-facts-and-summary-of-what-the-Rigveda-is-about/answer/Rami-Sivan?ch=10&share=cd091027&srid=ucZAt6)

What is the reference to the **hymn of faith** in the Rig
Veda? What are these? Does this kind of terminology exists?

---

> Creation x 3
>
> Dadhikras x 2
>
> Dadhikravan x 1
>
> Dadhikris x 1
>
> Dakshina x 1
>
> Dawn x 21
>
> Dice x 1
>
> Dream Charm x 1
>
> **Faith x 1**

Comment: This seems to be an opinion of one modern scholar, I don't think you'll find scriptural references for his categorization easily